# Chrome 69 hiding `www.` and protocol

Tags: google-chrome

With the current stable Chrome version 69,

when I surf to `https://www.google.com` the browser only shows `google.com` in the URL field.

I don't want Chrome to hide the protocol and I don't want Chrome to hide the subdomain.

How can I change these settings?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Taken from https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/chrome-69-removing-www-and-m-subdomains-from-the-browsers-address-bar/

> Open the Chrome browser and enter
> `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains`
> into the address bar. Then press Enter.
>
> Chrome will open a page that shows the "Omnibox UI Hide Steay-State
> URL Scheme and Trivial Subdomains" setting. Change this settings to
> `Disabled`.

@Google: For me this is a bug too. This "feature" is confusing and wrong, it should be removed.

`www.domain.com`, `m.domain.com` and `domain.com` are three completely different hostnames.

**Update:**

Only current working way is to install the Google extension to Report Suspicious sites: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/suspicious-site-reporter/jknemblkbdhdcpllfgbfekkdciegfboi

It will automatically enable www and protocol in the addressbar.

**Update 2021:**

Google has listened to the community and added the option "View" -> "Always show full URLs" to Chrome.

Comment: this isn't working for me... I'm on Mac OS 10.13.6 running Chrome 70.0.3538.67. I have `#views-browser-windows` enabled and `#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains` disabled. See https://i.imgur.com/LwPxeQjr.png. Any clue how to get it to work?

Comment: Turns out `#upcoming-ui-features` needs to be disabled as well to get this to work.

Comment: The correct URL is `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme` as of Chrome 73. They split out the "trivial subdomains" part into its own setting, as well as adding another setting that hides query args.

Comment: Wanted to make an extension that would enable just the sane URLs without tracking your browsing and found out this is not enabled by an API call, but by having a specific key (ie. signature of extension from Chrome webstore) in the manifest. Shady. [source](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/d739c811d0eac6380b3b09d0e4155eca35e08f48/chrome/browser/ui/toolbar/chrome_location_bar_model_delegate.cc#L75-L84)

Comment: If you don't find "View" -> "Always show full URLs", try right-clicking the url field and selecting "Always show full URLs" at the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's needed to get the scheme (aka protocol) and 'trivial' subdomains to be shown on Mac OS 10.13.6 running Chrome 70.0.3538.67:

- `chrome://flags/#views-browser-windows` set to enabled
- `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains` set to disabled
- `chrome://flags/#upcoming-ui-features` set to Default or disabled.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: This is not working in Google Chrome 79